# Launchctl minimal working example with Python

Tags: python, macos, launchd

I'd like to run a python script every minute using launchd. My plist file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.turtle.script.plist</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/python</string>
        <string>/Users/turtle/Desktop/turtle.py</string>
        <string>/Users/turtle/Desktop/data/data.txt</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>60</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This plist file looks good, as I get the following:

```
plutil -lint com.turtle.script.plist
com.turtle.script.plist: OK
```

The script works when I run it from the command line:

```
/usr/bin/python /Users/turtle/Desktop/turtle.py /Users/turtle/Desktop/data/data.txt
```

I load this plist via:

```
   launchctl load -w -F com.turtle.script.plist
```

I've alse tried:

```
sudo launchctl load -w -F com.turtle.script.plist
```

I load this job and the python script should write out a file to disk. However no file is ever produced. I examine the job with:

```
sudo launchctl list | grep com.turtle.script.plist
```

The output is:

```
- 1 com.turtle.script.plist
```

Can anyone help trouble-shoot the problem?

Comment: What's the problem? You never actually stated that.

Comment: Updated the question. The issue is that the code never executes it intended goal—to write a file to disk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like there's some environment dependence inside the script -- essentially, it assumes something about the environment it's running in that's correct when you run it by hand, but not when launchd runs it. Without knowing anything about the script, it's hard to point at what this might be, but I can suggest a few things to look at:

- `sudo launchctl` isn't a more powerful version of `launchctl`, it does something significantly different. You need to figure out which one you want, and use it.

  When you run `launchctl` as a normal user (e.g. `launchctl load`), it interacts with your user instance of launchd to manage Launch Agents -- items that run in your user session, under your user identity.

  When you run `launchctl` as root (e.g. `sudo launchctl load`), it interacts with the system instance of launchd to manage Launch Daemons -- items that run in system context, as root.

  You'll have to decide which is appropriate, based on what this script does.
- Check system.log (you can use the Console utility to view it, or `tail -f /var/log/system.log`) and see if it includes anything to indicate why the script is failing.
- Add entries to the launchd .plist to record the script's output, and see if that includes any error messages or other indications of what's going wrong:

  ```
  <key>StandardOutPath</key>
  <string>/tmp/turtle.out</string>
  <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
  <string>/tmp/turtle.err</string>
  ```

  It may help to edit the script to add debugging output, so you can tell more about how it's working (/not working).
- Does the script depend on having a particular working directory and/or environment variables? If so, add appropriate `WorkingDirectory` and/or `EnvironmentVariables` items to the .plist.

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work with your help. The issues was an environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try to write to `/tmp` which can be written by any user. i.e. change `/Users/turtle/Desktop/data/data.txt` to `/tmp/my_data.txt` if that is your output file.

Answer (score 1):

Your .plist file in `~/Library/LaunchAgents`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>local.tf.check_up</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Users/tf/.bin/check_up.py</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/local.tf.check_up.stderr</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/local.tf.check_up.stdout</string>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>60</integer>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/tmp/</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Your script `/Users/tf/.bin/check_up.py`:

```
#!/opt/local/bin/python

f = open('/Users/tf/Desktop/test.txt', 'a')
f.write('hello again 4\n')
f.close()
```

Please note that I use `python` from MacPorts, which lives in `/opt/local/bin/`. If you use a different python interpreter, replace the above line with whatever `$ which python` returns.

Make sure that your script is executable and only you have write access:

```
$ chmod 755 ~/.bin/check_up.py
```

To test the script: Run it and see that it works as it should:

```
$ ~/.bin/check_up.py
```

Load the LaunchAgent:

```
$ launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/local.tf.check_up.plist
```