# Launchd script running but output is missing (Exited with code: 2)

Tags: macos, shell, launchd

I am trying to execute a script about every minute using launchd

I added a new launchd job plist that looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.bpstatusboard.omnifocus</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/me/script.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>50</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The job is executed with the given time interval and generates the following log.

```
Apr 19 15:27:58 MacBook com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[153] (com.bpstatusboard.omnifocus[89895]): Exited with code: 2
```

Problem: The script should update a file but it's not. It's working correctly when I launch it manually in terminal. I couldn't find more details on exit **code: 2**. Any idea what stops the script to execute correctly?

Comment: Very hard to say without knowing anything about what's in the script; see [this previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990512/launchctl-minimal-working-example-with-python/15991343#15991343) for some troubleshooting options.

Answer (score 2):

Exited with code: 2

> [2 ENOENT](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/intro.2.html) No such file or directory.  A component of a specified
>   pathname did not exist, or the pathname
>                was an empty string.

Your script does not exist at /Users/me/script.sh.

Comment: Actually this is wrong.The script was found and executed. Some command in the script returned code 2. Had launchd not found the script it would have complained like this: Job failed to exec(3) for weird reason: 2