# How to run a Python command in a .plist?

Tags: python, macos, daemon, launchd

I'd like to add a LaunchDaemon that runs a Python file. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990512/launchctl-minimal-working-example-with-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1

Explicitly start the python interpreter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>tld.yourdomain.YourService</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/python</string>
        <string>/path/to/your/script.py</script>
    </array>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>root</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

### Option 2

- make your python script executable (`chmod +x /path/to/your/script.py`)
- put a she bang on the first line (`#!/usr/bin/python` or `#!/usr/bin/env python`)

and then just run your script directly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>tld.yourdomain.YourService</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/path/to/your/script.py</script>
    </array>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>root</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I should say that `RunAtLoad = true` is not the recommended way of starting a job. Really only do it if there's no other way. If you want to run it manually, just drop it and do `launchctl start tld.yourdomain.YourService`. To load the service `launchctl load /path/to/the/plist.plist` or stick it in `/Library/LaunchAgents`, `/Library/LaunchDaemons`, or `~/Library/LaunchAgents`.

And: `UserName = root` is only possible if it's a LaunchDaemon. If you don't need that, get rid of it too and make it a LaunchAgent (one instance *per user* as opposed to one for the whole system).