# launchd - how to keep script running in the background

Tags: bash, macos, plist, launchd

I have a simple script to upload the file to dropbox whenever it changes. I wanted to run it at system startup and keep it in a background to let the script watch the file.

I've created a plist, however it runs the script and exits with code 0.

plist

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.example.launchd.dropbox_uploader</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>sh</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>~/dropbox-uploader.sh; wait</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

(doesn't work neither with, nor without `wait` in the command)

script (it works fine and doesn't exit when run in command line)

```sh
#!/bin/sh

fswatch -o ~/file.txt | xargs -n1 -I{} curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload \
    --header 'Authorization: Bearer XXXXX' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' \
    --header 'Dropbox-API-Arg: {"path":"/backup/file.txt","strict_conflict":false,"mode":{".tag":"overwrite"}}' \
    --data-binary @'~/file.txt'
```

`launchtl list` output

```
 ~> launchctl list | grep com.example                                                                                                                       (base) 
-   0   com.example.launchd.dropbox_uploader
```

How to achieve my goal to have it run in the background? I'm not sure if there's an issue with my plist or script.

Comment: Not sure you should rely on tilde-expansion (`~') inside `launchd` - it's a `bash` feature.

Comment: Not sure what you are `wait`ing for, since you haven't started anything in the background.

Comment: Not sure why you are starting your script with `sh -c` since it already has a perfectly good shebang as its first line? Did you make it executable with `chmod +x ~/dropbox-uploader.sh` ?

Comment: Try capturing the script's output with the `StandardOutPath` and `StandardErrorPath` keys in your .plist (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990512/launchctl-minimal-working-example-with-python/15991343#15991343) for an example), and see if that gives you any info about what's going wrong.

Comment: @GordonDavisson thanks. Enabling output helped to solve the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enabling the file output as [Gordon mentioned in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65543410/launchd-how-to-keep-script-running-in-the-background/65548250#comment115881319_65543410) helped to find the reason.

The issue was:

```sh
/Users/me/dropbox-uploader.sh: line 3: fswatch: command not found
```

So changing `fswatch` to the absolut `fswatch` bin path `/usr/local/bin/fswatch` solved the problem. I've also replaced `~/` with the absolute path in the plist and made sure that script is executable.

Final script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

/usr/local/bin/fswatch -o ~/file.txt | xargs -n1 -I{} curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload \
    --header 'Authorization: Bearer XXXX' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' \
    --header 'Dropbox-API-Arg: {"path":"/backup/file.txt","strict_conflict":false,"mode":{".tag":"overwrite"}}' \
    --data-binary @'~/file.txt'
```

plist with file output enabled

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.example.launchd.dropbox_uploader</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/me/dropbox-uploader.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/me//dropbox.out</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/me/dropbox.err</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Well done. Thank you for sharing your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Edit crontab file with `crontab -e` and add the following to that file:

```
@reboot /path/to/job
```

This will run your job every time your system reboots and keep it running in the background.

Comment: They were asking about *launchd* suggesting how to create a cronjob is not even close to an answer.