# Why Is my LaunchAgent not interacting with Time Machine Mac OSX

Tags: bash, macos, automation, launchd, launch-daemon

I am currently writing an automation script for mac that takes control of time machine to run the backup at night.
the script is wotking when running from a terminal, interaction as expected with time machine but when i try to run it using a launchDaemon the time machine command seems to be omitted.
any idea why that  is?
Any help/insight would be greatly appreciated

the .plist file is root-owned and has a mod set at 600 (recommended by apple docs)

Here is the content of my .plist file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
            "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
        <dict>
            <key>Label</key>
            <string>local.automation</string>
            <key>ProgramArguments</key>
            <array>
                <string>/bin/bash</string>
                <string>/Users/<username>/<project>/automation.sh</string>
            </array>
            <key>RunAtLoad</key>
            <true/>
            <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </plist>
```

the automation.sh file is also a root-owned file  and the mod is set at 777.
the content goes as follows:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    PASS=$(security find-generic-password -l 'root password' -a dl -w | tr -d '\n')
    echo "$PASS" | sudo -S tmutil disable
```

Comment: There are a lot of security & privacy restrictions on access to both keychains and many parts of user home folders that're highly context-dependent, so it's likely they operate differently in a launch daemon vs interactively. Also, you shouldn't need `sudo` in a launch daemon, since they already run as root (& anyway it'd only apply to the `echo` command, not the `>>` redirection). I'd move everything outside your home folder, and remove the `sudo` part. And fix the script's perms! 777 = bad.

Comment: If it still doesn't work, you can add `StandardOutPath` and `StandardErrorPath` to the .plist to get logging info; see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990512).

Comment: Thanks for you help GD, you're right; it's a context permission issue, as the StandardOutPath & StandardErrorPath spits out the answer. after wrapping the bash script into a apple script app and alowing it full dis access it works. now I just have to figure out how to get this blasted thing to get launched by Launchd.

Comment: thanks for the perrm heads up too; I only set it that way for debugging purpose but i should get used to use the right perm instead.

Comment: also fixed the bash script of my question to reflect more what is causing the issue.

Comment: Wrapping it in AppleScript may open a different can of worms -- AppleScript tends to do things by interacting with other apps within a GUI context... and launch daemons don't run in a GUI context. So you have to be careful what features you use to avoid running into the limits of the environment it's running in. Good luck!

Comment: It took me ages to get it to work (I'm fairly new to programming as you might have guessed) but it finally did. the one thing you mentionned is your aversion to use a compiled apple script but i cant' seem to be able to get around this """
tmutil: disable requires Full Disk Access privileges.
To allow this operation, select Full Disk Access in the Privacy
tab of the Security & Privacy preference pane, and add Terminal
to the list of applications which are allowed Full Disk Access.""" without it.

Comment: I don't think there's anything inherently wrong with a compiled AppleScript, as long as the features you're using can work properly in the context of a launch agent. If it works, go for it!